# import modules from __init__.py in another folder

Tags: python, python-importlib

I have the following project structure:

```
- workflow/
            file1.ipynb
            file2.ipynb
            ...
- utils/
        __init__.py
        function_one.py
        function_two.py
        ...
```

I am working on file1.ipynb, so far I have found a way to import the variables defined in **init**.py through the following code:

```
utils = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('utils', '/home/utils/__init__.py').load_module()
```

Let's assume my `__init__.py` contains the following:

```
from .function_one import *
```

I can then use the variables defined inside the `__init__.py` file.

However, every time I want to call any of these variables I need to use the following syntax:

`utils.function_one ...`

I want to be able to write `function_one` without the `utils` at the beginning.

How can I import directly the variables defined inside the `__init__.py` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you don't import your module with the normal import mechanism: `from ..utils import *` or depending on where your python interpreter was started just `from utils import *` but if you insist on using `utils = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('utils', '/home/utils/__init__.py').load_module()` you can hack all values into your globals like this:

```
tmp = globals()
for attr_name in dir(utils):
    if not attr_name.startswith("_"): # don't import private and dunder attributes
        tmp[attr_name] = getattr(utils, attr_name)
del tmp

function_one(...) # should work now
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually can't import it using ..utils I get ImportError with no known parent package. any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from ..utils import *
```

Comment: I have the following error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package, can you help?